# How to provide GUI interface to all users of Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, gui

I have "Ubuntu Desktop" installed in VirtualBox in a Windows 7 PC.

How can I configure it to provide a GUI interface to every user I create in the Ubuntu?

Should I install "Ubuntu Server" to accomplish this?

Can this be done in Ubuntu? I remember working in a place where solaris was installed in a server and every user used to login using cygwin and get a solaris GUI desktop.

Can this be done? And what is this feature called?

I am asking this for an event for the following purpose.

I want to install ruby on rails in an ubuntu machine and create 5 users in the ubuntu.

These 5 users will have their own Windows 7 laptops.

These 5 users should be able to get their own GUI desktop on their Windows 7 laptop.

And can this be done by installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box in a Windows 7 PC? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand you well, you want that the users you are going to create in Ubuntu to be able to be able to access the Ubuntu desktop from their Windows PC.

To accomplish that, you will need to have on each Windows PC of the users a running X Server. Indeed in the Cygwin tools family there is one.

Personally, I use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) which provides a SSH, FTP, ... client, a local X Server and many other features.
Once the users are defined on the Ubuntu server, you will have to create a XDMCP sessions in this application.

**Remark**: by default the XDMCP protocol is not enabled in Ubuntu. To enable the XDMCP server in LightDM edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following section:

```
    [XDMCPServer]
    enabled=true
```

Then restart LightDM : `sudo restart lightdm`